# Unable to click on few items on website

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

The website I am trying to automate is betting website and I have a scenario to automate a horse betting.

I am using selenium 3.0 with Java

From the site I am able to travel to horse race but unable to select Tomorrow and select the race. I tried using xpath, class and other methods but unable to click on these button.

website is 
https://www.williamhill.com.au/

1 step. go to the above url
2. Select horse racing from top left corner or navigate to url (https://www.williamhill.com.au/racing?event=horseracing)
3.Click on Tomorrow   I am unable to do this
4. Select on particular race from the table (unable to this too)

```
package automationFramework;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class horseRacing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String exePath = "D:\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        //Launch the Online Store Website
        driver.get("https://www.williamhill.com.au/");
        Thread.sleep(5);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        String Title = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(Title);
        driver.findElement(By.className("MenuItem_text_N8V")).click();

        Thread.sleep(25);

       // driver.findElement(By.className("RaceGrid_raceTile_imG RaceGrid_raceDisabled_Q0m")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]")).click();




        // Print a Log In message to the screen
        System.out.println("Successfully opened the website www.Store.Demoqa.com");

        //Wait for 5 Sec
        Thread.sleep(5);

        // Close the driver
       // driver.quit();        


    }

}
```

Comment: Please can you share the code you have tried so far?

Comment: i am unable to access Australia from the site. so please provide your code

Comment: Provide the Exception you got

Comment: // driver.findElement(By.className("RaceGrid_raceTile_imG RaceGrid_raceDisabled_Q0m")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]")).click();

Comment: Exception Cannot find the element.

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='app']/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]"}

Comment: No need to login to the website, just need to access the website and travel. I am unable to post all code

Answer (score 0):

I tried to click "TOMORROW" and succeeded.

```
package test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class NavigateToAUrl {

    @Test
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.williamhill.com.au/racing?event=horseracing");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]")).click();

    }
}
```

Dot(.) is missing in your code `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]")).click();`

(Before //*[@id~)